# JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'

Tags: java, json

Подскажите как можно передать json с фронта в spring MVC контроллер:
класс:

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "PERSONS")
    public class Persons implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PERSONS_SEQ")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "PERSONS_SEQ", sequenceName = "PERSONS_SEQ")
        private Integer personId;


        @Column(name = "NICKNAME", nullable = false, length = 30, unique = true)
        private String nickname;


        @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false, length = 100)
        private String password;


        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
        private String lastName;

        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        @JsonManagedReference(value="person-city")
        @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID")
        private Cities city;


        @Column(name = "MOBILE_NUMBER", nullable = true, length = 30)
        private String mobileNumber;

        @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false, length = 30)
        private String email;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
        private Rollers role;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JsonManagedReference(value="person-cards")
        public List<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();

        public Persons() {
        }
        ...
        //all getters and setters
}
```

Json:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полагаю, что json не правильно сформирован. И отсюда возникает вопрос как можно передавать json, чтобы на фронте не писать кастомный его вариант для отправки на бек.

Comment: В чем собственно проблема? Непонятно как получить json на бэке или как его отослать на фронте?

Comment: проблему уже решил, она заключалась в том что объекты типа role, cards и city имели косяки